# Importing environment variables into HTML with Netlify

Tags: javascript, html, linux, netlify

I use environment variables within my JS code on my Netlify site and it works really well just setting them in "Build Environment Varibles", then using

`process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE`

I have an HTML file on Github that runs a couple of Netlify sites. I want to publish a *PUBLIC_URL* that is stored in Environment Variables for each site in Netlify. How could I use this whilst preserving and hiding my other "secret" environment variables that are stored on Netlify.

There is an article here about accessing them in the browser but that relies on /bin access which I do not have in Netlify

https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-get-environment-variables-in-the-browser/

Any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you are trying to do, but you can have access to execute the shell script that is in your repository. I took the example from the link and show the process commands to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the permission on the script to make it run if you want to use this method.

`bin/env.sh`

```
echo "env = {"
echo "  PUBLIC_URL: '$PUBLIC_URL'"
echo "}"
```

You setup the command to run in the site or the `netlify.toml` prior or as part of a build

```
chmod +x ./bin/env.sh && ./bin/env.sh > env.js
```

will output:

`env.js`

```
env = {
  PUBLIC_URL: 'your_value_from_environment_variable_PUBLIC_URL'
}
```

***NOTE:*** There are other ways to get the env variables into your javascript using build tools also. This answer is to show how to change your shell script to have permission to execute on Netlify.

Comment: Thanks @talves - Can I output this using HTML though? ```<div class="links" style="text-align:center;">
  <a href=%SHEET_URL% target="_blank">Sheet URL</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    const scriptURL = %SHEET_WEB_APP_URL%```

Comment: Sounds to me you want to output the `index.html` instead of the javascript. Sure, you could do that, but seems like a lot of work to me. What build tools are you using? These may be more appropriate for this.